# How I dynamically switch between different language resource files?

Tags: wpf, localization

In my wpf project, I have added two resource files:

```
Resources\English.resx and Resources\German.resx
```

in MainWindow.xml, I try to find the value from the resource file:

```
<Window x:Uid="Window_1" x:Class="LocalizationInvestigate.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Resources="clr-namespace:LocalizationInvestigate.Resources"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Uid="Grid_1">
        <Label x:Uid="Label_1" Content="{x:Static Resources:English.LabelHello}"></Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

For English, it works perfectly this way. However, based on the local language, how I can make it automatically switch to German by using: Resource:German.LabelHello?

Answer (score 6):

Well usually, you would create resource files with the standard culture string in its name. E.g.

> Strings.en.resx
>   Strings.en-US.resx
>   Strings.de-DE.resx
>   Strings.de-AU.resx
>   ...

The resource manager would switch the culture according to the `Thread.CurrentUICulture`. I think [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/299436/WPF-Localization-for-Dummies) is good article about it. The localization has also a fallback behavior, so that unknown cultures would be answered with the `en` resources.

The usage in the XAML would be.

```
<Label Content="{x:Static Resources:Strings.LabelHello}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have created another resource: fr-CA but when I set it like this: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-CA"); It is not possible to switch to fr-CA language file

Comment: Well since I don't know, what you've changed etc. It's a bit difficuilt to tell, what's wrong...

Comment: You shouldn't change the `CurrentUICulture`. You need to set `Strings.Culture` to the culture you want to use.