# Dynamically switch between languages using resx

Tags: c#, wpf

I made my test project as per

[How I dynamically switch between different language resource files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398833/how-i-dynamically-switch-between-different-language-resource-files)

I am unable to see the language change at runtime. I am sharing my codes and attempts here.

xaml file

```
    <MenuItem Header="{x:Static Resources:Resources.File}" VerticalAlignment="Center"> <!-- MenuFile-->
            <MenuItem Header="{x:Static Resources:Resources.New}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="{x:Static Resources:Resources.Open}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="{x:Static Resources:Resources.Close}"/>
        </MenuItem>


   private void English_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeCulture("en-US");
    }

    private void German_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeCulture("de-DE");
    }

    private void French_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeCulture("fr-FR");
    }

    private void Chineese_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeCulture("zh-CN");
    }

    public void ChangeCulture(string text)
    {
       Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(text);
       Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(text);
       Properties.Resources.Culture = new CultureInfo(text);
    }
```

The resource files that I created are of names Resources.de-DE.resx, Resources.fr-FR.Resx, Resources.zh-CN.resx and Resources.resx (Which contains default english localization)

Please guide, as to how to edit the xaml UI controls to switch text when respective language selection changes

Comment: If it's dynamic updates you need then you'll probably have much better luck using a [custom markup extension](https://www.wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html). That's what I use, it works really well.

Comment: What is the problem to use `Strings.en-US.resx`? You resources will be loaded according the current thread culture or use fallback

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Whenever I try to create Strings.en-US.resx resource file name, it creates an empty Strings.en-US.Designer.cs file. There by I will not be able to use the statements like MenuItem Header="{x:Static Resources:Strings.New}". Please Correct me if somethings else that I am missing to get this work

Comment: @NewLearner They should be empty, only main `Resources.resx` with default localization (English basically) contains autogenerated `Resources.Designer.cs` code, by declaring custom tool in file properties. You don't need to generate this code for every language. You can use en-US as neutral language in `Resources.resx` and define a separate files e.g. fr-FR or de-De in a separate files

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I have updated the code per your suggestion. Please refer my latest edits in the intial question posted. I'm still unable to change the UI to desired language changes.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, Also when I try to implement the following line of code, MenuFile.Header = DemoLangSupport.Properties.Resources.File; where MenuItem "File" Name = "MenuFile", then it works. Does this mean that I need to have names of every UI Item (like maybe text block, radiobutton, MenuItem, Window) populated like the above statement mentioned?

Comment: @NewLearner yes, you have to specify in resources all localizable strings from your application

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I understand, I need to mention all the localize strings in resource file. But my question was only when I mention in code .cs file like so then they work. MenuFile.Header = DemoLangSupport.Properties.Resources.File  Does this mean all the localized string in resource file needs specific mapping in .cs file as well? I thought reference of each of them in .xaml should take care once we change the current UI thread to desired language

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Sorry about asking again. Will you be able to help guide my last comment?

Comment: @NewLearner You should refer to localized keys only once, the exact language will be determined automatically according thread culture

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, Please refer my updated code in my initial edit. It still does not work as expected. Is there anything else that I am missing.